# Multiple if statements in process in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I'm not able to write vhdl syntax. But for the exam we must be able to read and interpret it.

The essence of the code is

```
process{
  if(start) 
    c := 0;
  end if;

  if ( c )
     ...
     c := false;
   else
     c:= true;
     ....
 end if;

}
```

Assuming that c=1 (is a variable) in the beginning. I'm having difficulties interpreting what happens here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the statements are inside a `process` they will execute sequentially just like software.

http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/components_vs_processes/

If you have `use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;` and `start` is set to `true` or `1` elsewhere in the code, then `if ( c )` would evaluate to `false` the `else` branch would be executed. Then `c` will be set to `false` and will retain that value until the next time this process executes (or some other process or combinatorial statement changes it).

If you don't have `use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;` the behavior is dependent on the compiler/synthesizer.

http://www.eda.org/vfv/hm/1153.html

There is a lot of code missing so I'm making a lot of assumptions here but hopefully you get the basic meaning.